# Combine more than 3 rotations (Quaternions)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, euler-angles

I have a 3D point and the **x,y,z rotations** (`qInitial`) for that point.
I want to rotate that point **more** (by some degrees that could be 0 up to 360) around **y** axis (`qYextra`). **How can I calculate the final Euler rotation** (`qResult.eulerAngles`) **that is a combination of these 4 rotations (x-y-z-y)**?

I have tried calculating the initial quaternion rotation, and the extra rotation to be applied. And then multiply these two quaternions. However, I get **weird results (probably gimbal lock)**.

Code in C#. Unity.

1.`Quaternion qX = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationFromBvh.x,Vector3.right);`

2.`Quaternion qY = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationFromBvh.y,Vector3.up);`

3.`Quaternion qZ = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationFromBvh.z,Vector3.forward);`

4.`Quaternion qYextra = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle,Vector3.up);`

`Quaternion qInitial = qY * qX * qZ; // Yes. This is the correct order.`

> `qY*qX*qZ` has **exactly the same Euler x,y,z results** as
> `Quaternion.Euler(rotationFromBvh)`

`Quaternion qResult = qInitial * qYextra;`

`return qResult.eulerAngles;`

I can **confirm** that the **code works fine** (no gimbal lock) when **4th rotation is 0 degrees** (`qYextra = identity`). Meaning that `qInitial` is correct. So, the error might be due to the **combination of those 2 rotations** (`qInitial` and `qYextra`) **OR** due to the convertion **from Quaternion to Euler**.

**EXAMPLE:** (`qYextra` angle is 120 degrees)

**RESULTS:**

`qInitial.eulerAngles` gives these results: [applying_qInitial_rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srkuc.png)

`qResult.eulerAngles` gives these results: [applying_qResult_rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2psfU.png)

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**

The expected results should be like `qInitial` but rotated 120 degrees around y.

Any suggestions? I haven't yet found a solution, and probably I won't.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: To me the correct order should be "qResult = qYextra * qInitial"

Comment: Thank you @MauricioCeleLopezBelon . I have just tried it, and I still get weird results (gimbal lock).

Comment: The problem might be when I convert Quaternions to Euler `qResult.eulerAngles;`?

Comment: Conversion to Euler angles might be the problem. Euler angles creates a map with the topology of a Torus and the Quaternions creates a map with the topology of a Sphere (projected from 4d linear space). A map from quaternions to euler angles is like a map from Sphere to Torus, it is not injective (one to one) and have singularities (gimbal lock). The following site explain the singularities in detail http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/ I would recommend to stick with quaterniona and avoid conversion to Euler angles.

Comment: Unfortunately my final data should be in Euler. So, I can't avoid the conversion. Thank you for the link you provided. I guess I will have to study more about Quaternions. Is there a methodology that estimates the proper way of the conversion to Euler? I mean, is it even possible to get **every time** the desirable Euler rotation from a Quaternion?

Comment: Please tell us what's the expected result you want?

Comment: I have updated my question, by giving an example.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you write:

> How can I calculate the final Euler rotation that is a combination of these 4 rotations (x-y-z-y)?

However, in your code, you write

```
Quaternion qInitial = qY * qX * qZ; // Multiply them in the correct order.
```

I don't know unity, but I would have expected that you would want the order of the rotations to match x, y, z, rather than y, x, z.

You stated that it works when the y-rotation is 0, in which case the place of the y-rotation in the order becomes irrelevant.

Do you get the correct result if you instead write the code below?

```
Quaternion qInitial = qX * qY * qZ; // Multiply them in the correct order.
```

Comment: Unity handle's Euler angles, when dealing with Quaterions, in the order Z, X, Y so multiplying 3 quaternions in the order Y, X, Z and then requesting the [eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) property of the result will be the same as providing those rotations in a single `Vector3` as an argument in `Quaternion.Euler`.

Comment: These two lines of code: `Quaternion qInitial = qY * qX * qZ;` and `Quaternion qAfter = qInitial * qRotationToBeApplied;` show that I want to combine 4 rotations. The first 3 INITIAL rotations are (qY, qX, qZ). The 4th rotation is qRotationToBeApplied. Speaking about the order of multiplication will agree with @Foggzie . Also, what I'm saying is that the code works fine when (4th rotation)`qRotationToBeApplied` is identity (0 degrees rotation).

Comment: I have edit my question, to avoid any ambiguities. Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely wrong q1{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0} no rotation q2{0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7} x 90 degree rotation, q1 * q2 gives {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7} wrong rotation which result in deformation!